Uso di "per" + infinito + "che" + "fare" in congiuntivo
In un esercizio di italiano ho trovato una frase che non capivo:

Per parlare che facesse non riusciva a convincerlo.

Un professore di italiano dell'università mi ha spiegato che significa

Per quanto parlasse, non riusciva a convincerlo.

Sono rimasta un po' stupita perché non avevo mai incontrato questo costrutto. Non è mica facile trovarne esempi. Infatti, sono riuscita a individuarne soltanto un altro in un libro ottocentesco (grassetto mio):

Frattanto il conte Lamarck segreto agente di Luigi trasferitosi a Londra onde persuadere Pitt a concorrere nella causa, per pregare che facesse, non riusciva a smovere il governo inglese dall'impassibile neutralità, che, dietro mature riflessioni, si era risoluto di mantenere.

Curiosamente, in un decreto legislativo del governo autonomo di Murcia che fa riferimento all'insegnamento delle lingue straniere, ho trovato che il costrutto

"per" + infinito + "che" + "fare" in congiuntivo

ha valore concessivo e l'esempio

Per parlare che facesse non riusciva a convincerli.

Qualcuno potrebbe spiegare come si usa o si usava (magari si usa poco nell'italiano attuale) tale costrutto?

Da italiano madrelingua non l'ho mai sentito dire. Potrebbe essere una forma strettamente regionale. Comunque suona sbagliato, e malissimo.

I would understand that sentence in the same way, but I cannot say it is the standard used way. I can say that people say che in phrases where I would not expect it, as in Faccio che andare. or Piuttosto che andare, avresti dovuto aiutarmi a trovare le chiavi.

A me invece non suona male, anzi ha decisamente un tono aulico, di altri tempi, ma con classe.
